# How to match nested strings and not separate string

Tags: python, regex, string, lexicon

I am trying to match a regex such that

```
hello ?color red ?name Yuri ? ? to the forum
```

will output

```
?color red ?name Yuri ? ?
```

Note that the beginning of the command always comes as (? + at least one letter) and the end of command is always (? + empty space)

I tried using the following regex:

```
/\?[^ ](.)*\?/g
```

However, if we have this input:

```
hello ?name Yuri ? welcome to ?forum Python ? It's awesome!
```

It matches:

```
?name Yuri ? welcome to ?forum Python ?
```

However, it should match separately (i.e. `[?name Yuri ?  , ?forum Python ?]` )

Please help! Again, command always starts with ?+letter and end with ?+whitespace

UPDATE 1:

However, the output is ['?color red ?name Yuri ? '] and it should be ['?color red ?name Yuri ? ? ']  (Two question marks) 
Note Nesting can be infinite i.e. ?name ?name ?color ?color    ? ? ? ?

So the idea is having ?command ? represent function calls, so let's say we have "?add 2 ?multiply 3 3 ? 5 ?" -> It should perform "?multiply 3 3 ?" which returns 9, and then it does "?add 2 9(which we got from the return) 5 ?" which adds up to 16

UPDATE 2:

Avinash's Answer from UPDATE 2 works GREAT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neeed to use a non-greedy regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "hello ?name Yuri ? welcome to ?forum Python ? It's awesome!"
>>> re.findall(r'\?[a-zA-Z].*?\?\s', s)
['?name Yuri ? ', '?forum Python ? ']
```

If you don't want to print the last empty space then add a positive lookahead assertion.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\?[a-zA-Z].*?\?(?=\s)', s)
['?name Yuri ?', '?forum Python ?']
```

**Update:**

```
>>> re.findall(r'\?[A-Za-z](?:\?[^?\n]*\?|[^?\n])*?\?\s', 'hello ?color red ?name Yuri ? ? to the forum')
['?color red ?name Yuri ? ? ']
>>> re.findall(r'\?[A-Za-z](?:\?[^?\n]*\?|[^?\n])*?\?\s', "hello ?name Yuri ? welcome to ?forum Python ? It's awesome!")
['?name Yuri ? ', '?forum Python ? ']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fA7xB8/1)

**Update 2:**

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'\?(?:(?R)|[^?])*\?', 'hello ?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ? ? ? ')
['?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ? ? ?']
>>> regex.findall(r'\?(?=\S)(?:(?R)|[^?])*\?(?=\s)', 'hello ?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ? ? ? ')
['?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ? ? ?']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fA7xB8/2)

Comment: One problem, >>> s = "hello ?color red ?name Yuri ? ? to the forum"
>>> re.findall(r'\?[a-zA-Z].*?\?\s', s)
Outputs: ['?color red ?name Yuri ? ']..........It should output:  ['?color red ?name Yuri ? ? '], the question mark is missing at the end

Comment: Why it correctly prints the `?` which follows the space? If you want it to be greedy then use this `re.findall(r'\?[a-zA-Z].*\?\s', s)` . However it won't works for the second case. Why you want it to greedy for first case and non-greedy for second case?

Comment: Well I want it to be nested. So for example if I used functions denoted as parenthesis, so "hello function(somestring) 33" should match "function(somestring)" . If I have "hello function('hello') beautiful function('word')" Should output "[function('hello'), function('world')]. However, in the second case, I have "function('hello' + function('world')). So I want the output to be "function('hello'+function('world'))" Hence that's why I want it to have two question marks in the case "hello ?color red ?name Yuri ? ? to the forum" and 2 separate entities in other case.

Comment: I know that there is a way to loop and ignore the question marks that are nested so something like /\?[^ ] ((\?[^ ].* \?)| .*[^\\*])* \?/g  <- I don't know how to syntax it correctly

Comment: Close, but I want infinite nesting support i.e. >> re.findall(r'\?[A-Za-z](?:\?[^?\n]*\?|[^?\n])*?\?\s', 'hello ?color black ?yellow sad ?dream red ?name Yuri ? ? ? ? to the forum')
['?color black ?yellow sad ?dream red ?name Yuri ? ? ']   <-- This should give out 4 question marks

Comment: i don't know what exactly you mean by infinite loop. Why the above gives you 4 question marks since the first four `?` is followed by a word character not a space.

Comment: Also, this seems to break: "hello ?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ? ? ? " to the forum     --> ['?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ?'] it should be ['?color ?size 22 red ?name Yuri ? ? ?']       Let's say we have "?add 2 ?multiply 3 3 ?  5 ?" -> It should perform "?multiply 3 3 ?" which returns 9, and then it does "?add  2  9(which we  got from the return) 5 ?" which adds up to 16

Comment: you actually need to use regex module, if you want to check for balanced `?` marks. check my update..

Comment: Is there a way to do it without regex module? It works, but let's say I want to use default "import re" can I do it just by nesting 3 levels?